# notify-send not working from cron

Tags: 14.04, cron, notify-send

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && usr/bin/notify-send "Hello world!"
```

I added the above command to the crontab, notify-send is working from terminal but not from the cron. Also checked the logs, its working every minute but notifications are not being displayed.